# Analytical solution to a 2nd order nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across this equation and was wondering if there exists an analytical solution.

$\frac{dy}{dx}(x+a+by^{n-1}) = cy^n\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

where $a,b$ and $c$ are real constants and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Does anyone know? I tried using the substitution $v=\frac{dy}{dx}$ but unfortunately did not get very far.

Comment: It looks pretty unpleasant---is there a reason you expect there be a closed-form solution?

Comment: No particular reason. I am pretty sure I will have to solve it numerically but was just curious to know what the community thinks.

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but I'd be quite surprised if there were a closed-form solution for generic $a, b, c$.

Comment: Well the values of $a,b,c$ represent physical properties of a porous material. If set accordingly, this ODE describes capillary wicking in a porous medium.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $t=x+a$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dt}(t+by^{n-1})=cy^n\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}$

$c\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}=(ty^{-n}+by^{-1})\dfrac{dy}{dt}$

You can consider as the ODE of the type http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=387